# C# Outlook COMException "Item has been moved or deleted"

Tags: c#, outlook, comexception

When running this loop to delete multiple of the same email I run into this exception. I believe it has to do with the length of oItems losing 1 due to an item being deleted, but it is not updated in the foreach loop.

```
            //Get the Inbox folder.
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            //Get the Items collection in the Inbox folder.
            Outlook.Items oItems = oInbox.Items;

                //loops through all inbox items
                foreach (object item in oItems)
                {
                    //checks to only use MailItems (no MeetingItems etc.)
                    if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        if (item.Subject != null)
                        {
                            if (item.SenderEmailAddress == "no-reply@virginpulse.com")
                            {
                                item.Delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It is always safe to to loop from length-1 down to 0 when deleting items from a collection in the loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that all collections in OOM are 1 based, not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use "`foreach`" when modifying a collection by calling `Move` or `Delete`.

Use a down "`for`" loop

```
for(int i = oItems.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{
  object item = oItems[i];
  ...
```

Comment: I haven't heard of a down loop before now. Thank you Dmitry!